# unable to login into a website using wget commands (shell scripting)

Tags: shell, unix, curl, sh

What I don't understand is what all input fields should I pass,I tried

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data "username=my_email_id" -d "password=my_pass" "https://ok.ru/https"     
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data "st.email=my_email_id" -d "st.password=my_pass" "https://ok.ru/https"
```

Should I pass all other input field values too? Is there any way where I can see if my login has been authorised, so that I can send a get request to other page after login.
The following is the form which is used in the site.

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.ok.ru/https">
    <input name="st.redirect" value="" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.asr" value="" id="field_asr" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.posted" value="set" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.originalaction" value="http://ok.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&amp;st.cmd=anonymLogin" id="field_originalaction" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.fJS" value="on" id="st.field_fJS" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.st.screenSize" value="1366 x 768" id="field_st.screenSize" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.st.browserSize" value="673" id="field_st.browserSize" type="hidden">
    <input name="st.st.flashVer" value="11.2.202" id="field_st.flashVer" type="hidden">
   <div class="hook">
       <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('st.field_fJS').value='on';
document.getElementById('field_st.screenSize').value=screen.width + ' x ' + screen.height;
document.getElementById('field_st.browserSize').value=OK.util.getVpHeight();
document.getElementById('field_st.flashVer').value=(okFlashVersion||[]).join('.');
       </script></div>
    <label for="field_email" class="anonym_login_l">Username, e-mail or phone number</label>
    <div class="it_w">
       <input name="st.email" value="" id="field_email" class="it anonym_login_it " maxlength="100" type="text">
    </div>
    <label for="field_password" class="anonym_login_l">Password</label>
    <div class="it_w">
        <input maxlength="50" name="st.password" id="field_password" class="it anonym_login_it " type="password">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="field_remember" class="anonym_login_rem">
            <input name="st.remember" checked="checked" id="field_remember" class="anonym_log_rem_check" type="checkbox">
            <span class="anonym_log_rem_check_tx">Remember me</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input name="st.iscode" value="false" type="hidden"><input value="Log in" class="button-pro __orange inlineBlock" type="submit">
    <a href="/cdk/st.cmd/anonymPasswordRecovery?st._aid=LeftColumn_Login_ForgotPassword" class="al-log">Forgot password?</a>
</form>
```

I also tried using

```
curl --user my_email_id:my_pass "https://www.ok.ru/https" -v
```

but got this

```
GET /https HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YmVya3NheUBtZS5jb206d2Fzd2VyZTEyMw==
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.ok.ru
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

I don't know how to proceed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using `wget` (which is what you have in your example), then you should just put all the params and values together, separated by `&` characters, in a single argument to the `--post-data` option; like this:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
     --post-data "st.email=my_email_id&st.password=my_pass" \
     "https://ok.ru/https"
```

> Should I pass all other input field values too?

That all depends on what you need. What do you want to get in the output? What are you using `wget` to access the form from the shell instead of just doing it a browser? You should explain that in your question.

> Is there any way where I can see if my login has been authorised, so that I can send a get request to other page after login.

You can check the output of the page from the shell (e.g., using `grep`) for some string that indicates the authentication succeeded.

Comment: I am trying to automate the login process and upload some videos.
It always gives me bad request. I am trying to save the output in a ttt.html file and then open it with browser, to see if the login was succesful or not. It always fail.

Comment: I tried it with curl too like this { curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt --data "st.email=my_id&st.password=my_pass" "https://www.ok.ru/https" > ttt.html }

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid, when I analysed the POST request and viewed the POSTDATA, I found it uses all the fields and that solved the problem. :)